# Netbeans file path

Tags: java, netbeans

When creating a file in Java using Netbeans.

I have a file "C:\myXml.xml"

However due to the nature of a library I am using the xml needs to be placed in "\data\myXml.xml" when using Netbeans.

Where would this file path relate to?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, you are asking where your file will be on the file system absolute path.. correct? It will be in the project folder root/data/myXml.xml

Comment: Thank you very much, that has sorted it, I was trying to put it with the .class / .java not quite sure why to be honest. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder (eg data) and copy your data files to this folder

Then in the Netbeans do the following:

Project Properties
   Run
   Working Directory

selecting your working directory.  Then run your project